# NameError: name 'df_true' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb

```
df_true_manual_testing = df_true.tail(10)
for i in range(21416, 21406, -1):
    df_true.drop([i], axis = 0, inplace = True)

df_false_manual_testing = df_false.tail(10)
for i in range(21480, 21470, -1):
    df_false.drop([i], axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

NameError: name 'df_true' is not defined ...

Comment: Can you share the entire traceback / error details

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 df_true_manual_testing = df_true.tail(10)
      2 for i in range(21416, 21406, -1):
      3     df_true.drop([i], axis = 0, inplace = True)

NameError: name 'df_true' is not defined

Comment: how are you getting the `df_true` dataframe?

Comment: df_true is my variable.

Comment: In the code given above you did not define the variable `df_true`, only the variables `df_true_manual_testing` and `df_false_manual_testing`.

Comment: where can i define the variable?

Comment: can you share the code where you define `df_true`

Comment: df_true = pd.read_csv("True.csv")
df_false = pd.read_csv("Fake.csv")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code to see the **exact** problem **directly**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
df_true = pd.read_csv("True.csv") 
df_false = pd.read_csv("Fake.csv")

df_true_manual_testing = df_true.tail(10)
for i in range(21416, 21406, -1):
    df_true.drop([i], axis = 0, inplace = True)

df_false_manual_testing = df_false.tail(10)
for i in range(21480, 21470, -1):
    df_false.drop([i], axis = 0, inplace = True)
```